# Using apply to find the optimum of 7 constants?

Tags: r, mapping, apply

I am trying to change the final `correcttot` function from a for loop to apply, but have been running into issues in trying to get the apply function to take the underlying values in `df`, the array which I will be applying it to.

```
   correcttot<-function(v,p,r){ 
        df<-expand.grid(i=1:10,j=1:10,k=1:10,l=1:10,m=2:10,n=2:10,o=1:10))
        df$correct3<-0
        df$correct3<- apply(df, 1:7, function(x) 
          percentcorrect((x$i)/10,(x$j)/10,(x$k)*20,(x$l)*20,x$m,x$n,x$o,v,p,r)
        )
        df$correct3
        }
        newvec2<-correcttot(v,p,r)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument of `apply` is not the column numbers, it's the number of the dimension. Your data frame only has two dimensions: rows (1) and columns (2).

For your analysis, set the second argument to 1 indicating you're applying the function to each row.

Comment: Thanks! and thats true even though it is dim7?

Comment: Data frames have two dimensions by definition. You can think of dimensions as the number of coordinates you need to identify a value. For a vector, you only need one value (e.g. the third value). For a data frame, you need the row and column (e.g. column 3, row 7). For a 3 dimensional array, you need the coordinates on all 3 dimensions (e.g. row 3, column 2, depth 4). For higher dimensions, you need even more coordinates. I'm pretty sure your df object only has two dimensions -- rows and columns.